# Invertible Borel set preserved mapping between $\times_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{C}$ and $[0, 1]$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

The following question is from *Linear Operators Part II* editted by **Dunford & Schwartz**, Exercise 15 in Chapter X.

Define $P$ to be the topological space $\times_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\,\mathbb{C}$ (where $\mathbb{C}$ is equipped with the usual topology). Show that there is a bijective mapping $h: P \rightarrow [0, 1]$ such that $h(A)$ is a Borel set iff $A$ is a Borel set.

**Edit**: Thanks for Eric's comment, I was reminded that this mapping does not have to be a homeomorphism because it only require the image of a Borel set to be Borel. Hence such a mapping could still exist.

Comment: $\mathbb{C}^{\mathbb{N}} \cong (\mathbb{R}^2)^{\mathbb{N}}) \cong \mathbb{R}^{2 \times \mathbb{N}} \cong (2^{\mathbb{N}})^{2 \times \mathbb{N}} \cong 2^{2 \times \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}} \cong 2^{\mathbb{N}}$.

Comment: There is a difference between homeomorphism and continuous bijection. The spaces $\mathbb{C}^\mathbb{N}$ and $2^\mathbb{N}$ cannot be homeomorphic as the first is compact and the second is not.

Comment: There is neither a homeomorphism nor a continuous bijection between these spaces.

Comment: @Mindlack Thank you for your answer. This implis a well-defined bijection but how about the condition "$h(A)$ is Borel iff $A$ is Borel"? Could you provide a more specific definition of your mapping?

Comment: @EricWofsey Because of the condition "$h(A)$ Borel iff $A$ Borel" and the bijectiveness, I believe it suffices to find a bijection that maps an open set to an open set and whose inverse does the same. Then KeeperOfSecrets reminds me that this is not possible ....

Comment: @KeeperOfSecrets You are right. If such a mapping exists, then we will have $h(A)$ open iff $A$ open" and hence $h$ will be a homeomorphism, which implies a contradiction.

Comment: @Sanae Kochiya: It works for most of the manipulations, as they are homeomorphisms. The only point not obvious is $\mathbb{R} \cong 2^{\mathbb{N}}$, which can be realized as a bijection preserving Borel sets the inverse of which also preserves Borel sets. But you can make the bijections $\mathbb{R} \cong [0,1] \cong 2^{\mathbb{N}}$ such that they’re isomorphisms wrt Borel $\sigma$-algebras (idea: take a continuous map and modify countably many values... if you get a bijection, it should be a satisfactory one).

Comment: "If $h(A)$ Borel iff $A$ Borel then $h(A)$ open iff $A$ open" is not true.

Comment: @EricWofsey I got what you mean. "$A$ is open" can only imply $h(A)$ is Borel but not necessary open. That is my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both $P$ and $[0,1]$ are Polish spaces, that is separable topological spaces admitting a complete metric. Then these spaces are Borel isomorphic by Theorem 15.6 from [Kech] (see below).

But first we recall the following definitions. A *measurable space* $(X,\mathcal S)$ is a set $X$ with a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal S$ on it. Measurable spaces $(X,\mathcal S)$ and $(Y,\mathcal T)$ are *isomorphic*, if there exists a bijection $f$ from $X$ to $Y$ such that $f(A)\in\mathcal T$ and $f^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal S$ for each $A\in\mathcal S$ and $B\in\mathcal T$. A measurable space $(X,\mathcal S)$ is a *standard Borel space*, if it is isomorphic to a measurable space $(Y,\mathcal B(Y))$, where $Y$ is a Polish space and $\mathcal B(Y)$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel subsets of $X$.

Now we cite [Kech]. Here $\mathbb I=[0,1]$, $\mathcal C$ is the Cantor set, and $\mathcal N=\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}$ endowed with the product topology.

(Remark that for the particular case from the question it suffices to find a Borel injection from $P$ to $[0,1]$ and then apply Theorem 15.7).

[image]

Referenced claims and their proofs:

[6.4–5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctU4p.png), [7.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6kE4.png),
[7.9.part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydBB1.png), [7.9.part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l258C.png), [14.12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duZYA.png), and [15.1–2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gDU5.png).

*References*

[Kech] A. Kechris, *Classical Descriptive Set Theory*, – Springer, 1995.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. According to comments from @Mindlack, the cardinality of $P$ and $[0, 1]$ are the same. Then can we directly apply **Theorem 15.6** (since by definition both are standard Borel space)? I guess I do not need **Theorem 15.7** here.

Comment: @SanaeKochiya Yes, we can. But Theorem 15.6 is a rather strong result with a long proof, so I tried to find a shortcut via Theorem 15.7. I guess there exists an even more short direct proof.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for letting me know this reference again.